# Activating windows 10 on Asus Zenbook Pro: No sticker

Tags: windows, windows-10, asus-laptop

So I have a Asus [Zenbook Pro](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-Pro-UX501VW) laptop which came with a pre-activated Windows 10. I ruined my OS and am now trying to reinstall. But I can't find any sticker for the MS Windows product key. The system also didn't come with any recovery media.

What is the work-around?

Comment: Windows 10 will automatically activate, if it doesn't, then call the Microsoft Activation Center.  There are dozens of Windows 10 questions like this with exactly the same answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention.  COA stickers were retired with Windows 7 devices.  Your license is stored in the ACPI table on the motherboard.  The Windows 8+ installation environment will automatically detect your license.  Additionally, Windows 10, automatically activates using a digital entitlement license.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for elaborating and sorry that I did not provide enough info in advance. The problem is that I used a Retail iso image for installation (erroneously) and am now stuck with having no product key. Should I contact the manufacturer company for a rescue DVD and fresh-install, or there is already a way to change the installed Windows to an OEM license without wiping out everything? i.e., what type of installation media automatically detects OEM license during installation or afterwards?

Comment: You can use (Retail) ISO to install a OEM licensed Windows 10 installation, additionally, that goes for any version of Windows by the way. It's a simple three step process (download The current ISO, Create the media, install Windows) that's the only thing you have to do

Comment: Then this is exactly what I have already done and the OS is not recognizing the digital entitlement. Anything else I can try before calling Microsoft?

Comment: No; there isn't

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by some research and saved Microsoft the hassle of an extra ring:
The laptop didn't come with a sticker showing the edition of manufacturer-provided Windows 10 license (there was only a Windows 10 logo underneath the system, with no hint to OS edition). So I used [ShowKey Plus](https://github.com/Superfly-Inc/ShowKeyPlus/releases/tag/ShowkeyPlus) to get the vendor-provided OS and its OEM registration key. Reading from ACPI, the license was Win 10 RTM Core (a.k.a. Home) Single Language. This was the rabbit hole's entrance: I had erroneously installed a Win Pro edition, and the whole installation/post-installation process avoided to tell me "hey, your system has an OEM registration license by the way, which doesn't match the version being installed. Did you know that?"

So I downloaded an official Windows 10 .iso matching my OEM Home license from Microsoft using their media creation tool. But when I used this media for installation, it spontaneously locked the installation mode on Pro edition with no option for changing to Home-single language. Turned out that it was due to my current unregistered OS which, although not activated, forced the installation process to lock on the Pro edition (weird!).

To circumvent, I followed [this](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-select-pro-edition-while-installing-windows-10/) link and created an ei.cfg file in the /sources folder of the USB installation media and used the following options to force installation of a Home-OEM edition:

**/sources/ei.cfg**

```
[EditionID]
Core
[Channel]
OEM
[VL]
0
```

But the above method didn't work, unless a product key file is also provided at the same path. I used the above OEM key extracted by ShowKey Plus to create the text file:

**/sources/PID.txt**

```
[PID]
Value=XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX
```

Hopefully, after all of these I could install the correct edition of Windows which got automatically activated.
Formating the hard drive and installing from scratch should have prevented all of this hassle, but was not an option for me since the system was a dual-boot setup and I didn't want to wipe the other OS.